# HashMap and garbage collection: do I need to call clear() before variable re-assignment?

Tags: java, android, collections, garbage-collection

Maybe it's a silly question but I'm not sure about the garbage collection process.

Consider this code:

```
private HashMap<String, Parameter> configuration = new HashMap<String, Parameter>();

...
//add some items to configuration
...

//now get another configuration
HashMap<String, Parameter> parameters = new HashMap<String, Parameter>();
for (String parameterName : configurationParameterNameList) {
    parameters.put(parameterName, reader.readParameter(parameterName));
}

//and reassign the variable
this.configuration.clear();
this.configuration = parameters;
```

Do I need to call `configuration.clear()` before reassign it? `Parameter` class contains only a few String variables inside.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you don't need to call `clear()`.

As long as nothing else has a reference to that `HashMap` it (and all of its entries) will become eligible for garbage collection as soon as you change `this.configuration` to another value.

Comment: Strictly speaking Android has a [Dalvik VM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)) and no Java VM. But besides this: yes, Android has a correct GC implementation.

Answer (score 2):

No, garbage collection in java is automatic. 
This means that if an object does not have a reference to it, it will be gotten rid of. 
So, like the above answer said, as soon as you take all the references away from the `Map`, it will become eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need. The original HashMap instance will be lost anyway. Initializing configuration doesnt make sense either.

```
private HashMap<String, Parameter> configuration;   
...
configuration = new HashMap<String, Parameter>();
for (String parameterName : configurationParameterNameList) {
    configuration.put(parameterName, reader.readParameter(parameterName));
}
```

Comment: The code is not complete, it make sense because the configuration can be accessed as an object property. The initizlization is made in the object creator. Thanks, anyway.